# Display count after updating every record

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

I have one xml file. File contains products name,product price.

I am updating product price of all products.But  I want to display the count after every record updated.

like If i have 10 products in xml file then it will show

- 1 updated of 10

then

- 2 updated of 10

and finally it will show 10 updated of 10.

I am displaying progress bar but I want to display count of record also while updating.

Following is the C# code.

Here I am loading the xml file then it will read the `productcode` node and update the price with what we have enter in textbox.

After updating every product price I want to display the record count.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

using APIReaderLib;
using APIReaderLib.DataObjects;

namespace VAPIReader
{
    public partial class UpdateProducts : Form
    {
        public UpdateProducts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
               XmlDocument m_xmld = null;
               XmlNodeList m_nodelist = null;
               XmlNode m_node = null;
               XMLPostManager manager = new XMLPostManager();

               m_xmld = new XmlDocument();

               m_xmld.Load("C:\\Users\\pooja.b.EDREAMZ\\Desktop\\s&p\\Final1.xml");

               m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/xmldata/Products");

               foreach (XmlNode m_node_loopVariable in m_nodelist)
               {
                   m_node = m_node_loopVariable;

                   string Productcode = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText;
                   string productprice = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText;

                   Console.Write(" Product Code: " + Productcode  + "Product Price:" + productprice);

                   decimal strprice =Convert.ToDecimal( productprice);
                   decimal strtextprice = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);

                   decimal test = strprice + (strprice * strtextprice/100);

                   string updatedprice = test.ToString();

                   UpdateProduct(updatedprice, Productcode);

                   XmlDocument readDoc = new XmlDocument();
                   readDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\pooja.b.EDREAMZ\\Desktop\\s&p\\Final1.xml");
                   int count = readDoc.SelectNodes("/xmldata/Products").Count;

                   progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
                   // Set Maximum to the total number of Users created.
                   progressBar1.Maximum = count;
                   // Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
                   progressBar1.Step = 1;

                   progressBar1.PerformStep();

                   // Updates the label to show that a file was read.
                   label2.Text = Convert.ToString(progressBar1.Value) + "updated of " + count;
            }
        } 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error updating product " + ex.Message);
            }
            this.Close();
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
        }

        private void UpdateProduct(string price, string Productcode)
        {
            xmldata1 data = new xmldata1();
            data.Items = new xmldataProducts[1];
            data.Items[0] = new xmldataProducts();

            data.Items[0].ProductPrice = price;
            data.Items[0].ProductCode = Productcode;

            string productXML = Utils.GetProductXML(data);
            string APIURL = Utils.GetAPIPostURL(ImportMode.Update);

            XMLPostManager manager = new XMLPostManager();

            string response = manager.SendXMLToURL(APIURL, productXML);
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Increment counter value when you update XML record.

Comment: What kind of app? Winforms? Console? WPF? ASP.NET ?? What have you tried?? Show us the code you have that updates your product prices....

Comment: Please check above code. let me know your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just have a counter in your code and increment it inside your `foreach` loop, and output it:

```
 m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/xmldata/Products");

 int totalCount = m_nodelist.Count;     // insert this - total count
 int handled = 0;                       // insert this - currently handled count
```

and then after handling the node, when you updated the progress bar, include this:

```
progressBar1.PerformStep();

handled++;    // increment the handled count

// output message of "updated x of y nodes"    
Console.WriteLine("Updated {0} of {1} nodes", handled, totalCount);
```

Also: you should set up the progress bar only **once** - outside your `foreach` loop! Something like:

```
progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
// Set Maximum to the total number of Users created.
progressBar1.Maximum = totalCount;   // you've already determined that total count before!
// Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
progressBar1.Step = 1;
```

and then you don't need to constantly re-create your progressbar, and you don't need to re-load that XML document inside your `foreach` loop for every node you process - that's done **once** before the `foreach` loop and that doesn't change during processing.

Answer (score 0):

You just keep a counter while updating. After each record is done, add to the counter and display that value where ever you want.

UPDATE:
Take the count variable out of the loop.

e.g.

```
int count = 0;

foreach (XmlNode m_node_loopVariable in m_nodelist) 
        { 

           count += 1;
```

Comment: Yes,But Its not working for instance if I have 10  records then.After completing foreach loop it is showing me directly 10 updated of 10. It is executing in one thread. Please advise

Comment: I have done change as you said but still its showing me directly 
10 updated of 10. that for loop executed in one thread that why it is showing after updating 10 records. after updating one record it will continue with the second  then third and so on. then when it will done with 10 records then its showing me the count.

Comment: see the updated code. You were getting the count of all the products, when you only needed to update the count by 1 each time as you are looping through each product.